# How to nest a list of dataframes into a list of a list by an index variable in each dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split

I have a list of dataframes. All dataframes in the list have a common (metadata) variable *Index*. I want to use this *Index* variable to group this list of dataframes into a nested dataframe by this *Index* variable. That is, to group all the dataframes with `Index == "X"` into one list, `Index == "Y"` in another list, `Index == "Z"` in still another list, etc. The `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the different index values in the different dataframes, and resulting lists should be in one large list.

Here is a sample dataset.

```
testlist = list(
  data.frame(
    A = 1:10,
    B = 11:20,
    Index = "A"
    ),
  data.frame(
    A = 21:30,
    B = 31:40,
    Index = "B"
  ),
  data.frame(
    C = 41:50,
    D = 51:60,
    Index = "A"
  )
)
```

In this case, I'd like two lists in a list. The first would have two dataframes that correspond to the two dataframes with `Index == "A"` and the other list with only one dataframe that corresponds to `Index == "B"`. I've used `group_split` to split a dataframe into a list, but it does not work on lists to create a list of lists. However, something like that is what I've been trying to achieve.

In my actual dataset there are two *Index* variables which refer to the number of rows and columns of the datasets. Please feel free to recommend any other strategies you may think of.

Thank you.

Comment: `split(testlist, sapply(testlist, \(x) x$Index[1]))` if Index is a constant as in your examples.  You may want to post an example of the data with two index variables as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a possible solution?

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)

testlist = list(
  data.frame(
    A = 1:10,
    B = 11:20,
    Index = "A"
  ),
  data.frame(
    A = 21:30,
    B = 31:40,
    Index = "B"
  ),
  data.frame(
    C = 41:50,
    D = 51:60,
    Index = "A"
  )
)


testlist |> 
  pmap_dfc(~as.data.frame(c(.x,.y))) |> 
  select(A = 1,B = 2, Index = 3)
#> New names:
#> • `c(.x, .y)` -> `c(.x, .y)...1`
#> • `c(.x, .y)` -> `c(.x, .y)...2`
#> • `c(.x, .y)` -> `c(.x, .y)...3`
#>     A  B Index
#> 1   1 11     A
#> 2   2 12     A
#> 3   3 13     A
#> 4   4 14     A
#> 5   5 15     A
#> 6   6 16     A
#> 7   7 17     A
#> 8   8 18     A
#> 9   9 19     A
#> 10 10 20     A
#> 11 21 31     B
#> 12 22 32     B
#> 13 23 33     B
#> 14 24 34     B
#> 15 25 35     B
#> 16 26 36     B
#> 17 27 37     B
#> 18 28 38     B
#> 19 29 39     B
#> 20 30 40     B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Magnus. Unfortunately, instead of unlisting the lists, I'm actually hoping to do the opposite: to list the list of dataframes into a list of a list, so your solution isn't achieving what I am looking for.